# why getting an image width sometimes work well but sometimes not in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want to check a width and height of the uploaded image.
So I used JS to get those ones, but it returns 0. Sometimes it works, but usually it doesn't.
I don't know the reason, so please let me know the reason why this happens.

```html
<label class="add-label" title="イメージ追加" v-if="!uploadedImage">
  <i class="material-icons add-rich-image" v-if="!uploadedImage">add</i>
  <input type="file" @change="onFileChange" class="imageBtn" ref="richImage" accept="img/*">
</label>
<div class="richmenu-img-area">
  <img class="richmenu-img" :src="uploadedImage" ref="uploaded" ondragstart="return false">
</div>
```

```js
onFileChange(e){
  let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  if(!files[0].type.match(/image.*/)){
    alert("イメージファイルをアップロードしてください。")
    return;
  }
  this.imageFile = files[0]
  this.createImage(files[0]);
},
createImage(file){
  let reader = new FileReader();
  let image = new Image();
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    image.src = e.target.result;
    console.log(image.width)//********************* sometimes ok but sometimes 0
    console.log(image.height)//********************* sometimes ok but sometimes 0
    this.uploadedImage = e.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

To reproduce your problem, use the snippet below and follow the below steps:

1. Upload a file.
2. Upload another file.
3. Upload the same file in step 1.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('change', createImage);


function createImage(e){
  const files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

  const reader = new FileReader();
  const image = new Image();
  
  reader.addEventListener('load', function(e){
    image.src = e.target.result;
    console.log(image.width, image.height);
  });
  
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="file" accept="image/*">
```

#### Explanation

You should see the first 2 uploads returning `0 0` and the third upload returning correct image width and height.

This is because images need to be fully loaded before the metadata (i.e., width and height) becomes available.

The reason when you upload the same file again yields the correct result is because the image is loaded from before and is saved in cache by browser. So the next time you attempt to load it the browser already have that information to pass to your code.

#### Solution

If you need to get the `.width` and `.height` every time a file is uploaded, you should listen to when the image element is loaded:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('change', createImage);


function createImage(e){
  const files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

  const reader = new FileReader();
  const image = new Image();

  // Get the image data only after it is loaded.
  image.addEventListener('load', function(e){
    console.log(image.width, image.height);
  });
  
  reader.addEventListener('load', function(e){
    image.src = e.target.result;
  });
  
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I also realized that the image was not fully loaded, so i added        this.$nextTick(function () {...}           which is the code for the action after loading in Vue.js.